# Creating .so and .a in UNIX

Tags: unix

How to create a .so and .a file in UNIX. Do we have any standard utility for it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*.a - **a**rchive library 
to create it compile your sources:

```
gcc -c -o foo.o foo.c
gcc -c -o boo.o boo.c

ar -rsc yourlib.a foo.o boo.o
```

so - position independent code shared library

```
gcc -fPIC -shared  -soname,libfoo.so.1 -o libfoo.so.1.0 foo.c boo.c
```

Comment: second (-fPIC) creates *.so libraries, Your sources needs to be compiled this way, no other way (I don't know other ways).

Answer (score 4):

```
#create shared library
gcc -Os -fPIC -c test.c
gcc -shared  test.so test.o 


#create static library
gcc -Os -c test.c
ar rcs test.a test.o
```

Answer (score 2):

The .a is also called a static library, and the .so is also called a dynamically loaded library.

I like the [Program Library HOWTO](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO.html).

> This HOWTO for programmers discusses
>   how to create and use program
>   libraries on Linux. This includes
>   static libraries, shared libraries,
>   and dynamically loaded libraries.

The [Yo Linux tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) is also useful.

> This tutorial discusses the philosophy
>   behind libraries and the creation and
>   use of C/C++ library "shared
>   components" and "plug-ins". The
>   various technologies and methodologies
>   used and insight to their appropriate
>   application, is also discussed. In
>   this tutorial, all libraries are
>   created using the GNU Linux compiler.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this [Makefile](http://code.google.com/p/anacrolix/source/browse/examples/libdemo/Makefile) I wrote when I was new to C. It clearly shows how to generate and correctly link `.a` and `.so` files from a [simple demo source](http://code.google.com/p/anacrolix/source/browse/examples/libdemo/).